# how TimeZone.getDefault() works?

Tags: java

> My server is in US and I am accessing the application in India through
>   web browser, in that case what `TimeZone.getDefault()` will return? 
>   If it returns Time Zone based on India on basis of what it will return?
>
> I have changed in control panel setting to different locale and
>   different time zone of the system even though it is not changing based
>   on my settings.
>
> I have written the code as fallows...

```
def dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.DEFAULT,DateFormat.DEFAULT,Locale.getDefault())
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault())
```

Comment: What do you mean by "accessing the application"? Where is the call to `TimeZone.getDefault()` running? And what have you already observed in your testing? At the moment your question is too vague to give a good answer to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's going to return the timezone of the JVM TimeZone.getDefault() is executed on.  So if the application is running on a server in India, it will be something like "Asia/Calcutta".

Answer (score 1):

Default time zone is usually set for host, not user or application.  In your case it will be default time zone for a server where your application is running, most probably US time zone.

Try to run command `date +%Z` in Unix console on server.

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of 'where this code executes'. If you are talking about a web application which is being accessed by a browser in India, the kind of date you get will be in US. Well, unless you set the proper locale and timezone for the user's session. In frameworks like [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/calendar.localization.html) once you call `setLocale()` on the application it sets the timezone as well, but in other platforms you might have to explicitly use a date formatter with a specific timezone.

Comment: The `Locale` doesn't normally include the time zone.